# Async await call is not working properly in my Console Application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Async await call is not working properly in my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Start the HandleFile method.
    Task<int> task = HandleFileAsync();

    // Control returns here before HandleFileAsync returns.
    // ... Prompt the user.
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait patiently " +
        "while I do something important.");

    // Do something at the same time as the file is being read.
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You entered (asynchronous logic): " + line);

    // Wait for the HandleFile task to complete.
    // ... Display its results.
    task.Wait();
    var x = task.Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + x);

    Console.WriteLine("[DONE]");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<int> HandleFileAsync()
{
    string file = @"C:\testfile.txt";
    Console.WriteLine("HandleFile enter");
    int count = 0;

    // Read in the specified file.
    // ... Use async StreamReader method.
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string v = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // ... Process the file data somehow.
        count += v.Length;

        // ... A slow-running computation.
        //     Dummy code.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            int x = v.GetHashCode();
            if (x == 0)
            {
                count--;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("HandleFile exit");
    return count;
}
```

Its expected output should be

> HandleFile enter
>
> Please wait patiently while I do something important
>
> HandleFile exit

but output is coming

> HandleFile enter
>
> HandleFile exit
>
> Please wait patiently while I do something important

Comment: Why do you expect that outcome? What is your reasoning behind that assumption? The task could be scheduled to run after the console writeline of the "please wait" message.

Comment: becaue Its async and It should print next message while completing function call.

Comment: First, try switching to `async Main`.

Comment: Now error coming, the program does not containt Main entry point.

Comment: No, it.might print the next message before the next message. The task could be scheduled to run after the console writeline of the "please wait" message.

Comment: So sometimes it will have the expected outcome, sometimes not.

Comment: And replace `task.Wait();` with `await task;` as every `async` needs an `await`

Comment: I deleted my previous project. again created new project and run this code.but same issue is occuring.

Comment: Could you try adding `Task.Yield()` after `await reader.ReadToEndAsync()`? It is possible that `ReadToEndAsync` completes synchronously for some reason, in which case the `Task.Yield()` will force the `HandleFileAsync` method to complete asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question have no issue, I checked It by running your code in my PC. Please once again check your console application creating method. If there is problem, please share the detail of creating your application method as well.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: I am not creating my application first time, I can create console application and i can run, it works fine.but now problem is coming.so i asked the issue.

Comment: Yep. I commented but i think he did not see my comment in many comments. so i suggest him a solution. no worries If It works for him.

Comment: Great. Thank you. It was my fault. You're saying right. I was doing mistake while creating console application. Now running fine.

Comment: Glad. you see your mistake and please next time try to solve small mistakes by yourself.